# Do I need to import react in every file?

Tags: reactjs

I've found out that components without `import React from 'react';` lines works well.

I've added `import React from 'react';` to the first line of .jsx files conventionally. And I saw many open source with this line.

Then why do we add this line unnecessarily?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You no longer need to `import React from "react"`. Starting from the release 17 of React, JSX is automatically transformed without using `React.createElement`.
However, other exports like hooks must be imported.

Answer (score 9):

if you use a builder like esbuild, unfortunately you will need to import react in every file because it would be an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined`

but if you use the default builder you don't have to import react in each file

Comment: I am using eslint, do you have an idea of how to tell vscode to ignore warnings `'React' is declared but its value is never read` ?