# Do we need import react and react-dom nowadays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, import, react-dom

[image: 1]

Hi,I want to code something about REACT COMPONENT.
When I type these two lines in Visual Studio Code:

import React from 'React';
import  ReactDOM  from 'react-dom'.;

As screenshot shown,VS suggests me to delete these two lines.
Do we no longer need to import 'react' and 'react-dom' nowadays?

[image: 2]

Comment: what makes you think "VS" is suggesting anything about those lines ... of course you need to import what you need to use

Comment: if you dont use anything from the imports, vs might suggest to delete those until you do

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Comment: these 2 lines are transparent in VS,and VS suggests to fix it with deleting

Comment: Given that those are the only two lines in the file, of course they're unused. Will you need them for the rest of what you're planning to put in that file? That depends what it is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe's comment [linking to React docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html#whats-different-in-the-new-transform) is pretty important here -- from the blog, "_Note how our original code did not need to import React to use JSX anymore!_" There [should be times you do _not_ need to import React for JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71726118/1028230) -- though admittedly it's impossible to tell in this question. As jonrsharpe also says, "_Given that those are the only two lines in the file, of course they're unused._" More context is needed.

Answer (score -1):

2 things here :

First, it says to remove because it is an unused import.

Second, to make sure this a React Component, you have to declare the import.