# React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Just created a new react app to learn but I always get this error and since I just started learning I don't understand why it's happening**

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check your code at index.js:9.
printWarning @ react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87
react-dom.development.js:28439 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.development.js:28439:1)
    at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:28465:1)
    at reconcileSingleElement (react-dom.development.js:15750:1)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15808:1)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19174:1)
    at updateHostRoot (react-dom.development.js:19883:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21615:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
```

**Here's my indexjs**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';

let name = "Anything";
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Genres</li>
        <li>Mylist</li>
      </nav>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Welcome {name}</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit a maxime voluptatum adipisci soluta commodi sequi numquam temporibus. Quod magnam animi possimus dolore consectetur. In alias aliquid natus ea odit fugiat possimus tenetur, aspernatur ullam. Dolorem eos rem magnam ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***I just started learning to code so, I am still pretty new to this. I have been following tutorials about javascript and react but they never get this error and I couldn't find any help online so, I'm getting nowhere with this***

Answer (score 1):

React needs to be in scope when using JSX, try adding this at the top of your App.js file:

`import React from 'react';`

Comment: I don't think it's the problem. In the newer vesion of react it's not needed to import React from 'react'. When I'm writing JSX  I don't import React in my components. 

"**_You no longer need to import React from "react" . Starting from the release 17 of React, JSX is automatically transformed without using React..."_**
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71725865/do-i-need-to-import-react-in-every-file]